# JDBC format ResultSet as tabular string?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, resultset

When I query a database in the MySQL command-line interface I get some nice prettified tabular output:

```
mysql> select * from users;
+------------+--------------------------------------+------------+
| IGN        | UUID                                 | AdminLevel |
+------------+--------------------------------------+------------+
| GamerBoy   | 0fcba4a5-f039-4771-ae22-bf203ed89c1c |          3 |
+------------+--------------------------------------+------------+
```

Now, in java I have to use a `ResultSet` to store the result of a query, and here is the code I currently have:

```java
String query = String.join(" ", Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 2, args.length));
System.out.println("Querying the database with: " + query);
try {
  Statement stmt = dbConnection.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
  System.out.println("Query parsed successfully!");
  /* What need to go here? I want to output the result of the query
   * in the same way that the MySQL tool would - some prettified String.
   */
} catch (SQLException exception) {
  System.out.println("Query failed: " + exception.getMessage()) ;
}
```

How do I get a string containing the sort of output that MySQL would give me?

---

Basically, I want to make a java program which can query a database - the query can be different every time, it is user-chosen - and then outputs the result of the query in the neat tabular format that MySQL uses.

How can I do this?

Comment: ResultSet does not keep the formatting used by MySQL.  If you want it to look like MySQL you would have to create that formatting yourself.

Comment: @SusannahPotts I am just beginning with JDBC and to me the problem is not so trivial as you make it out to be; I do not even know what table the user is querying, let alone the names or numbers of columns etc.

Comment: At no point did I say that it would be trivial or that I considered it as such.  I was simply stating that ResultSet doesn't keep formatting and any formatting that you want you would have to create.

Comment: There are many libraries to help with this chore of transforming data from a ResultSet. Examples include [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org), [SQLContainer](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/sqlcontainer/sqlcontainer-architecture.html) in [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin) ([demo](http://demo.vaadin.com/sqlcontainer/addressbook)), [RowSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/rowset.html) interface with various implementations, and more. It is a big field. But first do some of it yourself with plain Java code to get oriented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to process the `ResultSet` object `rs` by yourself.

```
while(rs.next()){
  String ign = rs.getString("IGN");
  // ... get uuid and admin level
  System.out.println(ign + uuid ...);
}
```

Use [`ResultSet#getMetaData()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData()) if you dont know the column names:

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount() ; // returns the number of columns
for(int i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++){
    rsmd.getColumnName(i);
}
```

Be aware that the columns are 1-indexed, that is, the first column name would be: `rsmd.getColumnName(1);`.

check [Java8 ResultSetMetaData API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html)

Comment: But I don't know the potential fields (column names?) - Idon't even know what table the user will have queried from.

Comment: Thank you for getting me started, I ended up also having to use the [`ResultSetMetaData#getColumnTypeName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnTypeName(int)) method to check whether I should be using `getString`, `getInt` etc.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`ResultSet.getMetaData()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData()) to find out about each column and no of columns and design table accordingly.

Here is a dirty untested sample.

```
    private String processResultSet(ResultSet rs) throws Exception
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int totalCols = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        int[] colCounts = new int[totalCols];
        String[] colLabels = new String[totalCols];
        for(int i = 0; i < totalCols; i++)
        {
            colCounts[i] = rsmd.getColumnDisplaySize(i+1);
            colLabels[i] = rsmd.getColumnLabel(i+1);
            if(colLabels[i].length() > colCounts[i])
            {
                colLabels[i] = colLabels[i].substring(0, colCounts[i]);
            }
            sb.append(String.format("| %"+ colCounts[i] +"s ", colLabels[i]));
        }
        sb.append("|\n");

        String horizontalLine = getHorizontalLine(colCounts);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            sb.append(horizontalLine);
            for(int i = 0; i < totalCols; i++)
            {
                sb.append(String.format("| %"+ colCounts[i] +"s ",rs.getString(i+1)));
            }
            sb.append("|\n");

        }


        return (getHorizontalLine(colCounts)+sb.toString());
    }

    private String getHorizontalLine(int[] colCounts)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 0; i < colCounts.length; i++)
        {
            sb.append("+");
            for(int j = 0; j < colCounts[i] + 2; j++)
            {
                sb.append("-");
            }
        }
        sb.append("+\n");

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: This seems very useful... do you mind posting a quick and dirty example of how I can loop through each ResultSet entry and then each column?

Comment: that just caused my server to crash.... a tick too long, guessing it infinite looped.

Comment: Maybe because some of the table entries contain new lines?

Comment: @minseong its possible that you have way too much data pulled in that query, and had a out of memory error. And since this is a quick and dirty code, I am not handling any edge cases. You should modify it to fit your requirements. And if you like this answer, you can mark it accepted ;)

Comment: I'm getting spurious results for rsmd. getColumnDisplaySize(i+1)...column 1 should be 12 and I'm getting 196605.  When I use getPercision(i+1) I get 786420.  I've looked at the rsmd and these numbers are in the rsmd.fieldPackets.length for the columns I'm looking for.